# How to transfer information between the main window and an AppWindow in a UWP app?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

So I'm developing an app and some items need a properties window to open. I have been following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/app-window) on how to use `AppWindow`.

What I'm not able to figure out is how to push information between the main window and the properties window. So like when it's first opened, I need to give it all the stored properties to be displayed, but the properties window needs to push any changes back to the main window to be stored and used.

I have very rudimentary code, but I think it demonstrates what I'm doing.

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{

    ...

    public async Task OpenPropertiesWindow()
    {
        //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/app-window

        AppWindow properties_appwindow = await AppWindow.TryCreateAsync();
        Frame appWindowContentFrame = new Frame();
        appWindowContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(PropertiesWindow));
        ElementCompositionPreview.SetAppWindowContent(properties_appwindow, appWindowContentFrame);

        properties_appwindow.RequestSize(new Size(300, 400));
        properties_appwindow.Title = "Properties";

        //send data to the textbox in PropertiesWindow

        properties_appwindow.Closed += delegate
        {
            appWindowContentFrame.Content = null;
            properties_appwindow = null;
        };

        await properties_appwindow.TryShowAsync();
    }
```

PropertiesWindow.xaml:

```
<Page
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBox x:Name="txtbox_property1" PlaceholderText="property1"/>
            <Button x:Name="btn_apply" Content="Apply" Tapped="ApplyPropertiesButton_Tapped"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

PropertiesWindow.xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class PropertiesWindow : Page
{
    public PropertiesWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ApplyPropertiesButton_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string data_from_txtbox = txtbox_property1.Text;

        //push this data_from_txtbox to MainPage
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me out? I will also need to run another updating method on `MainPage` whenever a property is changed, so I need some kind of trigger for when data is sent back.

Comment: [Did you look at this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-to-app/)?

Comment: Frame.Navigate takes an optional secomd parameter that is an object that is passed to the page. You can use that to pass the MainPage to the PropertiesWindow. And then, the PropertiesWindow can pass itself (`this`) to a method on the `MainPage` to let the MainPage know who to talk to.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Frame` you have created after you navigate to get access to the `Page` instance:

```
var page = (PropertiesWindow)appWindowContentFrame.Content;
//do something with the page, for example
page.SomePublicMethod(myData);
```

To go the other way around, you can use the `Window` API to access the main app window from an `AppWindow` page:

```
private void ApplyPropertiesButton_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string data_from_txtbox = txtbox_property1.Text;

    var rootFrame = (Frame)Window.Current.Content;
    var page = (MainPage)rootFrame.Content;
    page.SomePublicMethod(data_from_txtbox);
}
```